# Regarding convergence of infinite sum of projections in norm

Tags: hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $\{P_n\}$ be a sequence of pairwise orthogonal non- zero projections in $B(H)$. That is $\{P_nP_m=P_mP_m=0\; \text{for} \;n\neq m\}$. If  $P=\sum_{n}P_n$ , then how do I show that $\|P-\sum_{j=1}^{n}P_n\|=1$ for all $n$?

Comment: You mean the $P_n$ are non-zero orthogonal projections and $P_nP_m=0$ (if $P_n$ is a non-orthogonal projection then $\|P_n\| > 1$)

Comment: @reuns Made the edit.

Comment: Most projections (ie. $P^2=P$) are not orthogonal projections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that $P_n$'s are non-zero orthogonal projections. Note that $P_n x=0$ whenever $x$ is in the range of $P_m$ with $n \neq m$. If $x$ is a unit vector  in the range of $P_{n+1}$ then $Px=x$  and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} P_k (x)=0$ so $\|P-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} P_k\| \geq 1$. Do you  know how to prove the reverse inequality? I will add  a  proof if you cannot do  this.

Hint: If $P$ and $Q$ are orthogonal projections with $PQ=QP=0$ then $P+Q$ is also a projection. Hence all finite sums of $P_i$'s are orthogonal projections.

Comment: So basically we need to show that $\|\sum_{j=n+1}^{\infty}P_j\|\leq1$. But this is still an infinite sum. Your hint helps me deal with finite sums only.

Comment: The fact that all finite sums of $\sum P_nx$ are bounded in the norm by $\|x\|$ proves that the infinite sum is convergent. This is required right in the beginning to see that $P$ is well defined. @user31459

Comment: @user31459 $\|\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}P_nx\|^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=m}^{n}\|P_nx\|^{2}\leq \|x\|^{2}$ because $P_m+P_{m+1}+...+P_n$ is an orthoginal projection.